# install Ubuntu to usb

Tags: system-installation, usb-drive

Is it possible to install Ubuntu to usb drive and boot from it without installing it to the inbuilt hard drive? I have installed it on the hard drive before but now I want to install it to usb...please tell me the procedure if its possible..

Answer (score 0):

You need at least 2 GB USb disk and then use Startup Disk Creator on Ubuntu

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

(btw it is the first hit I got on Google when I specified "ubuntu on usb")

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
Under Ubuntu, you can launch already installed [usb-creator.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/USBInstallationImages)
Under all systems, you can use [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/)

Note that usb-live is great to test a little and install but it is quite slower.

Comment: This answer fail to offer a solution,"USE THIS" should be a comment, not an answer. Please add steps to actually install Ubuntu to the USB.